# ExecutorService is not executing the runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, executorservice

I'am using ExecutorService to make multiple call to hereMaps webService.
When i execute my code in my dev environment it works but when i deploy this code in production it doesn't work. task.taskExecute() is not executed, any idea why can this happen ?

```
                    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(treadsNomber);
                    for (final HereMapsSpeedLimitationService task : HereMapSpeedLimitationTasksList) {
                        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try{
                                    task.taskExecute();
                                    }catch (JsonParseException e){
                                        AddressRetriever.getLogger().addException(LogLevel.CRITICAL, "Erreur :", e);
                                    }catch (SQLException e){
                                        AddressRetriever.getLogger().addException(LogLevel.CRITICAL, "Erreur :", e);
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        AddressRetriever.getLogger().addException(LogLevel.CRITICAL, "Erreur :", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Comment: Please cut down your code to be a [MCVE]. There is lots of probably irrelevant code here, which makes it hard to see the actual problem.

Comment: @ Andy Turner its ok now ?

Comment: Better. But is the body of `taskExecute()` relevant? And the body of the Runnable? They're not being run in the thread executing the for loop. If you basically pass a no-op Runnable instead, do you still get the same issue?

Comment: when i pass a no-op runnable i don't get the same issue. the task is provoking the issue